# Tcl: How to run an executable on another machine

Tags: tcl

While working on machine xyz (could be linux or windows) - I need to start an executable program on another windows machine (just trigger would do).
How could that be done.

Comment: What you're looking for is a way to do remote execution. Can you run a custom service on the Windows machine? That can simplify things quite a lot. Also, does the program that you're planning to run need any sort of administrative privileges?

Comment: I have my user credentials as admin. So is there a way to run it from my user login - it will be a windows machine.

Comment: Hi Donal, I was also looking up online (its the first time i am doing this), could i possibly start a socket server on the remote win machine - configured as a service that starts on system start/ reboot. The sole purpose of that service to be to trigger an application from command line with some args. Eventually i could be using a tcl client socket from the linux terminal to call that service.
Thanks.

Comment: use the two tcl scripts: one that is started when windows starts, it listens for a command then execute your program with the required arguments.

Comment: how can i start such a command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments provided, did the following purely on trial basis:
- Ran a custom listening tcl script on target machine (this was monitoring a shared file for writes) - also trying to use the win task scheduler to make it run each time user logs in
- On another machine that was to send command to the remote machine for exe execution, wrote a tcl proc to write to the shared file mentioned above

Thus whenever the file was written to, the script running on the target machine read the instructions and executed accordingly.

This is working for now, there are a few issues i am still facing but I think will get better eventually.

Comment: I worked on an industrial system once that did exactly this for networking. Do yourself a favour read up on how to write a web app - currently that's the easiest, low-friction way to do something like this mainly because it's so easy to google for solutions.

Comment: Thanks slebetman - i will definitely give it a try - I am just beginning in this area and for now this crude implementation worked - but i am sure there will be better ways of handling this